# Rails Conditional Validation in Model from Controller Session Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model, controller

I am trying to conditionally validate *full_name* and *zip* based on whether a visitor is part of a test (Visitors that are part of the test will have certain session data).  I am able to pass true/false from the leads controller to the customer model via customer.visitor_test(), but I can't access **@test** from **in_test?** in the model.  What am I missing?

customer.rb

```
/* Stripped down code */

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor    :test

  validates :full_name, presence: true, if: :not_in_test?
  validates :zip, presence: true, if: :in_test?

  def visitor_test(bool)
    @test = bool
  end

  def in_test?
    @test
  end

  def not_in_test?
    !self.in_test?
  end
end
```

leads_controller.rb

```
/* Stripped down code */

class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    session[:zip] = zip
    session[:email] = email
    session[:full_name] = full_name
    session[:email_opt_in] = email_opt_in
    session[:phone] = phone

    listing = Listing.where(id: listing_id).first

    customer = create_or_update_customer_from_session(listing)

    customer.visitor_test(/* true || false */)

    if customer.errors.blank?
      /* Do something */
    else
      /* Something else */
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Stripped down code */

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor    :test

  validates :full_name, presence: true, if: :not_in_test?
  validates :zip, presence: true, if: :in_test?

  def in_test?
    test
  end

  def not_in_test?
    !in_test?
  end
end
```

`attr_accessor` provides setter and getter.

```
/* Stripped down code */

class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    session[:zip] = zip
    session[:email] = email
    session[:full_name] = full_name
    session[:email_opt_in] = email_opt_in
    session[:phone] = phone

    listing = Listing.where(id: listing_id).first

    customer = create_or_update_customer_from_session(listing)         customer.test = true     

    customer.save

    if customer.errors.blank?
      /* Do something */
    else
      /* Something else */
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Pardeep.  I tried your solution, but the `test` attribute is returning `nil` in `in_test?`.

Comment: `customer.test = true` should be set before calling save request `customer = create_or_update_customer_from_session(listing)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Placing `customer.test = true` before the `create_or_update_customer_from_session()` call actually gave me an `undefined local variable or method 'customer'` error.  But you led me to the correct solution.  I need to call `customer.save` after `customer.test = true`.  So the if you can update your answer to reflect the following:  
    customer = create_or_update_customer_from_session(listing)  
    customer.test = true  
    customer.save  
then I can accept your answer.

Comment: @fernando good to hear, your problem solved.I have updated answer.